# Object has not method error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using following code but it returns following error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'userInput'
> ```

Here is the code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hrx7/):

```
var ClickEvent = function (event) {
    this.ev = $('.' + event);
    this.ev.on('click', function () { this.userInput(); });
};

ClickEvent.prototype = function () {
    return {
        userInput: function () {
            console.log('user');
        },
        
        show: function () {
            console.log('show');
        }
    };   
}();

var c = new ClickEvent('event');
```

I am calling `userInput` function inside `on()` callback function but it returns above error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: put a `console.log(this)` inside the click event handler function (where you now have userInput). What does it tell you ? :)

Comment: Is the `$` jQuery? If it is, add the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the execution context(`this`) inside the click callback handler does not point to the `ClickEvent` instance, it is referencing the dom element that was clicked.

You need to use

```
this.ev.on('click', $.proxy(function () { this.userInput(); }, this));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N8zdA/)

or

```
var that = this;
this.ev.on('click', function () { that.userInput(); });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N8zdA/2/)

Answer (score 2):

`this.userInput()` is nested within the callback function, and thus is scoped within it. You could externalize the `this` instance you need as follow:

```js
var ClickEvent = function (event) {
    var $this = this;
    $this.ev = $('.' + event);
    $this.ev.on('click', function () { $this.userInput(); });
};
```

Comment: What is the meaning of $this? I mean is this var that = this; different than var $that = this; ?

Comment: @x4ph4r No, there's no difference, `$this` is just the name of a variable, just like `that`.

Answer (score 0):

the `"this"` inside your `onclick` function is referencing `"this.ev"` which is

```
"$('.' + event);"
```

not your object with `"userInput"` and `"show"`.